# Web content not loading until it is brought into view even though the page loaded already

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am new to angular and creating a site. When I am on this page http://metrotennis.com/raymond/#/usta/brooklyn on mobile, trying to scroll down the page, the content will not load until the content is brought into view. I am using ui-router

```
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        .state( 'usta', {
            url: '/usta',
            views: {
               "main": {
                   controller: 'usta',
                   templateUrl: 'templates/usta.html'
                },
            }
         })
         .state("manhattan", {
             parent: 'usta',
             url: '/manhattan',
             controller: 'manhattan',
             templateUrl: 'templates/manhattan.php'
          })
    }
])
```

So I am inserting this div into the parent page to grab the new file:

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

Please let me know if there is something I am missing or if it is just because I have a heavy page.

Thanks!

Comment: Please read [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. You need to include the code here on Stack Overflow, not on a third party site.

Comment: Tried to update @MikeMcCaughan. Trying not to insert to much code to overburden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add:

```
html{
    overflow-y: scroll!important;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```